# Can you catch the error code and exception information thrown using Powershell to call C# console Application?

Tags: c#, .net, powershell

I have a powershell script that watches a folder for data file to be dropped into it. When it sees a file, it then begins to process it by calling my console application that is written in C#. Now, I can return an error code and determine if the job failed or not. If it fails, it sends out an email. What I am wondering, is if I can return an int error code AND the exception that was thrown on the stack, so that when powershell gets the error code, it can also add the exception that occurred n my C# application to an email it sends out. I currently get the email, and then have to go look at a log file where the C# application writes all exception handling to.  IS this possible, or is my only option to write different int values that mean each exception, and then have a case select inside my powershell script to get what the actual error was that caused the fail?

Thanks in advance.

Instead of emailing "File failed....." and getting exit code 0 or greater, can I also recieve the exception that actually cause the error in the powershell script?

Brief example of the Powershell code below with some code removed for certain purposes:

==================================================================================

```
  $emailFrom = e@example.com"
  $emailTo = "me@example.com"
  $emailSubject = "Overlay File Processing Failed"
  $emailBody = ""
  $fileCtr = 0

  $logPath = "E:\path to log file"
  Add-Content -Path $logPath -Value "[$([DateTime]::Now)] Checking for files."

  if ($fileCtr -gt 0) 
  {
      Add-Content -Path $logPath -Value "[$([DateTime]::Now)] Found $fileCtr files to process."
ForEach ($_Name in $pdffiles) 
{
   $fullfile = $pdfdir + $_Name
   $StartProc = Start-Process F:\my C# .exe -ArgumentList "$fullfile $outdir" -RedirectStandardOutput "e:\my C# app log.txt"-Wait -PassThru
   $exCode = $StartProc.ExitCode

   if ($StartProc.ExitCode -ne 0) 
    {
        Get-Content -Path e:\log.txt
        $emailBody = "processing failed for file " + $pdfdir + $_Name

        send-mailmessage -from $emailFrom -to $emailTo -subject $emailSubject -body $emailBody -smtpServer $emailServer

    Add-Content -Path $logPath -Value "[$([DateTime]::Now)] Processing failed for file $fullfile. Exit Code:$exCode" 
        $fileparts =  $_Name.ToString().split(".")
        move-item $fullfile ($fileparts[0] + "{0:yyyyMMddhhmmss}.pdf" -f (get-date))
        } else {
        Add-Content -Path $logPath -Value "[$([DateTime]::Now)] Processing succesfull for file $fullfile"
        $fileparts =  $_Name.ToString().split(".")
        move-item $fullfile ($fileparts[0] + "_{0:yyyyMMddhhmmss}.pdf" -f (get-date))
    }
}
} else {
   Add-Content -Path $logPath -Value "[$([DateTime]::Now)] No files to process."
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer ot my question. YOU CANNOT DO WHAT I AM WISHING TO DO. The routes that can be taken are to write a log file from the console application, and then read it in from the powershell script, or just use certain int values that represent certain failures, and switch through them to report the corresponding error.

Comment: Or, since you wrote the console application in C#, perhaps you can fairly easily convert it to a class library and then use it inside the PowerShell process.

Comment: I did not think of that. What benefit would this have?  That would allow me to do what I want then wouldn't it?????

Comment: Yeah.  You can catch the exception in PowerShell.

Comment: Can you please tell me how to do this?   I have searched everywhere. I know that windows environment uses the last exception in a global variable, but I need the exception to be caught by the powershell script that executes my program.  Since you must have a Main[args] of type int or void, how do I send this back to the powershell code?   - Thanks @ OldFart.